# Symfony2 Eclipse plugin, so hard to get it working?

Tags: eclipse, symfony, eclipse-plugin

My setup is a fesh install of **Eclipse Classic 3.7.1** plus **Symfony2 plugin** from [its update site](http://pulse00.github.com/updatesite/):

- My workspace is `C:\Users\Marco\Documents\Eclipse`.
- I've extracted `Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.0.4.zip` inside it (a new folder `Symfony2` ws created).
- Then i created a Symfony2 project (path to `C:\Users\Marco\Documents\Eclipse\Symfony2`)
- I've modified PHP build path of my project (as explained [here](http://pulse00.github.com/Symfony-2-Eclipse-Plugin/)) to include `app`, `src` and `vendor folder`.

**Result**: hundred of validation errors mainly because of vendor folder, as the plugin was completely ignored. Auto-complete works only in PHP classes but not in Twig files.

Answer (score 1):

at the time of your writing the plugin was still alpha. please report any issues you encounter with the plugin on github (https://github.com/pulse00/Symfony-2-Eclipse-Plugin) otherwise i can't investigate the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse Project Properties, Validation section: 
- Enable Project specific settings 
- Select XML Schema Validator Settings ("..." button)
- add exclude group
- add a rule to "exclude group" which excludes doctrine/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd

Answer (score 0):

Some errors like

> cos-nonambig: WC[##other:"http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"] and WC##other:"http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.

are not coming from the Symfony2 Eclipse Plugin. It's XML/XSD validation errors that occur because those xsd/xml files are invalid from the Eclipse's XML/XSD validator point of view. If you exclude these folders from the build path, the PHP Indexer/Parser won't visit those folders, but Eclipse's XML/XSD validator still check them.

For more information, check out [this issue on pulse00's Github](https://github.com/pulse00/Symfony-2-Eclipse-Plugin/issues/52) and [this other one on Symfony's official Github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2122).